# Is Possible to set only english keyboard active in android application

Tags: android

I am new to android Application, We develop a android App in English Language, But User go to the setting and change the language other than English.
and type in App other then English. Now how to prevent to user doesn't use Other 
then english please Suggeest.

Answer (score 0):

yes you do.... follow this procedure---

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
InputMethodSubtype ims = imm.getCurrentInputMethodSubtype();
String localeString = ims.getLocale();
Locale locale = new Locale(localeString);
String lang= locale.getDisplayLanguage();
```

here lang represents the keyboard language.
You can compare this with english. If this is english you can allow the user otherwise you can do whatever desired....

Comment: Hi Raj, You give me any example.

Comment: hi Raj we have use api level 10(using Xamarin) where inputmethodsubtype doesnt support please suggest..